# Differential quadrature method fails on 4th order PDE with nonlinear b.c. as grid gets denser

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I am using differential quadrature method (DQM) to solve the following initial-boundary value problem:

$$\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} + \mu \frac{\partial w}{\partial t} + C_0 \frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial x^4}=0$$
$$w(0,t)=X_b(t)$$
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=0}=\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}\bigg|_{x=1}=\frac{\partial^3 w}{\partial x^3}\bigg|_{x=1}=0$$

Here $X_b(t)$ (`Xb[t]` in the code below) is the input in the system. For harmonic function

$$X_b(t)=2G_1 \cos(2\Omega t)$$

as input, `NDSolve` works perfectly. For other inputs also, simulation goes on properly. But for the input

$$X_b(t)=2G \cos(2 \Omega t) (w(1,t)+\alpha \; w(1,t)^3)$$

High frequency oscillations grow and the simulation results become more and more inaccurate, as number of grid points (`Np` in the code below) increases. If `tmax` is large or `Np > 10`, then the simulation fails with warning

> NDSolve::ndsz: singularity or stiff system suspected.

I have solved this problem with another method, there is no high frequency oscillations present.

The following is my trial. The PDE has been discretized to `Np - 1` ODEs with DQM.

```
Np = 10; G1 = 0.05; Ω = 1; μ = 0.05; tmax = 10; a = 30;
ii = Range[1, Np]; X =  0.5 (1 - Cos[(ii - 1)/(Np - 1) π]); 
Xi[xi_] := Cases[X, Except[xi]];     
M[xi_] := Product[xi - Xi[xi][[l]], {l, 1, Np - 1}]; 
C1 = C3 = ConstantArray[0, {Np, Np, 4}];
Table[If[i != j, C1[[i, j, 1]] = M[X[[i]]]/((X[[i]] - X[[j]]) M[X[[j]]])];, 
      {i, 1, Np}, {j, 1, Np}];
Table[C1[[i, i, 1]] = -Total[Cases[C1[[i, All, 1]], Except[C1[[i, i, 1]]]]];, 
      {i, 1, Np}];
C3[[All, All, 1]] = C1[[All, All, 1]]; 
C3[[1, All, 1]] = 0;
C3[[All, All, 2]] = C1[[All, All, 1]].C3[[All, All, 1]]; 
C3[[Np, All, 2]] = 0;
C3[[All, All, 3]] = C1[[All, All, 1]].C3[[All, All, 2]]; 
C3[[Np, All, 3]] = 0;
C3[[All, All, 4]] = C1[[All, All, 1]].C3[[All, All, 3]]; 
C3r4 = N[C3[[All, All, 4]]]; 
C0 = 1.8751^-4;
K1M = C0 C3r4[[2 ;; Np, 1 ;; Np]];
Y1[t_] := Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, 2, Np}];
α = -0.001;
```

Input `Xb[t]` is substituted in the system of equations through a column vector `YV[t]`.

```
Xb[t] = 2 G1 Cos[2 Ω t] (Subscript[x, Np][t] + α Subscript[x, Np][t]^3);
YV[t] = Flatten[{Xb[t], Y1[t]}];    
eqns = Thread[D[Y1[t], t, t] + μ D[Y1[t], t] + K1M.YV[t] == 0];
Lg = 1; bt = 1.8751/Lg; ξ = X[[2 ;; Np]]; 
y0 = -0.5 a (((Cos[bt*ξ] - Cosh[bt*ξ])-0.734*(Sin[bt*ξ] - Sinh[bt*ξ]))); 
X0 = -y0; X0d = 0 y0;
s = NDSolve[{eqns, Y1[0] == X0, Y1'[0] == X0d}, Y1[t], {t, 0, tmax}, 
            Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", Method->{"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}},
            MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
            AccuracyGoal -> 11, PrecisionGoal -> 11]; //AbsoluteTiming
plot1 = Plot[Evaluate[Subscript[x, Np][t] /. First@s], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Results obtained with *version 11.1* for `Np = 6` and `8` are given below. For `Np = 8`, fluctuation in the output increases.

[image: Np=8,9]

For `Np = 12`, it gives warning

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 7.129860412016928`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

[image: Np=12]

I have used different options of `NDSolve` to deal with the stiff system, but still it is not working.

I thought that, if I use `NDSolve` in smaller interval then it may be successful. So I made the code in which initial conditions (for ith iteration) are calculated based on the output from previous iteration (i - 1). But multiple `NDSolve` simulation also didn't work.

I have tried different initial conditions also, but the warning remains. Can someone please help me to solve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Use `Plot[Evaluate[Subscript[x, Np][t] /. First@s], {t, 5.5, 6.5}, PlotRange -> {-70, 30}]` to see that a rapidly growing high frequency oscillation is superimposed on the slowly oscillating solution that you appear to desire.  Using `WorkingPrecision -> 30` along with `SetPrecision[{eqns, Y1[0] == X0, Y1'[0] == X0d}, 30]` does not help, which makes me think that the oscillation may be real.

Comment: `WorkingPrecision -> 60` with `Rationalize[{eqns, Y1[0] == X0, Y1'[0] == X0d}, 0]` produces the same result!  All this suggests that rapid, growing oscillations are real.

Comment: The similar physical problem has been solved using another technique. Such very high frequency oscillation with very high amplitude tends to a wrong result. Here, there is no problem in case of simple harmonic input.

Comment: Here, if \Omega=1.2, then there will not be any problem. \Omega=1 causes one type of instability. That actually does not lead to high frequency oscillations or such a large value.

Comment: Actually, there still are high frequency oscillations, but they do not grow much.  In any case, the instability looks real, because it is insensitive to the choice of numerical methods.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks..
High frequency oscillations are present for other cases also. That I had noticed in many other different simulations. But with large amplitude and going out of bound is in correct.

Comment: @Hari Do you try to extend the numerical method developed for the linear system to the nonlinear one? It looks like you use pseudospectral method involved boundary point `Xb[t]`. Thus nonlinear excitation been added for every grid point. In this case the system respond is unpredictable.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I am using differential quadrature method in which derivatives are evaluated at certain grid points. and Xb[t] is the displacement of a boundary point. Because of Xb nonlinear term is being added in all the equations. But, this doesn't make system unpredictable. Even it is linear (\alpha=0), then also it gives errors or fails. I have got correct result using another technique. I think problem is due to harmonic variation of the coefficient with time. xb=cos(2 Omega t) fun(x_Np).

Comment: @Hari   Thank you very much you are mentioned DQM to clear how matrix `K1M` been constructed. With this update your code looks wrong in the part of boundary condition Xb. I have update for my answer then.

Comment: So, this ODE system is a discretized PDE? Can you add the original PDE (and as much background material as possible) so we can check it easier?

Comment: At the moment my opinion is similar with @bbgodfrey and Alex i.e. the something is wrong with the system itself. The same result is obtained using the new-in-12.1 system modeler related function: `model = CreateSystemModel[
  Flatten@{eqns, Y1[0] == X0 // Thread, Y1''[0] == X0d // Thread}, t]; 
sim = SystemModelSimulate[model, 6]; SystemModelPlot[sim, "x_10"]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have used fixed frame of reference in the analysis of the base excited cantilever (clamped end is displaced). Substituting Xb in the final ODE, I don't think, it can be used. In my code, K1M[[All,2;;Np]] provides the effect of base displacement through Xb (not equal to zero). So, I have considered Xb into YV.

Comment: @Hari Why don't you use first point `X[[0]]=0`, but have used all other points? Can you add explanation of the physical background of your code? It looks like nobody can understand what you try to solve.

Comment: @AlexTrounev At X[[1]]=0, first grid point, governing equation is not defined. Only the boundary condition, given displacement is defined. So only that can be used.

Comment: @Hari Could you explain what is initial data and how you implemented boundary conditions $w'(0,t)=w''(1,t)=w'''(1,t)$?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have followed the paper for that.  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4389170

Comment: @Hari Then you can check equation (20) in this paper and first boundary condition there as $u(0)=0$. This is what I have used in my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrounev But in my case, displacement BC is non-homogeneous. w(0)=2G cos(2\Omega t) (w(1)+\alpha w(1)^3). So, first column of K1M is not made zero. I am using it with frame of reference as earth.

Comment: @AlexTrounev what do you mean by initial data? Initial conditions are given in my code.

Comment: Do you forget to update the image and corresponding description? Tested in _12.2_, the solution suddently becomes unstable when `Np=10`, and remains stable for `Np=8` and `Np=9`.

Comment: @xzczd I have 11.1 version, in which it works only for Np=6, but in **Matlab 2015a (ODE45)** I  found it working up to Np=10. Further using **ODE23s**, error says **matrix is badly scaled or singular**. I prefer mathematica, as it is very fast in numerical computation.

Comment: Then it's a bit interesting. Just tested in _v8.0.4_ (in _v8_ we need `Y1[0] == X0 // Thread, Y1'[0] == X0d // Thread` instead of `Y1[0] == X0, Y1'[0] == X0d` BTW) and _v9.0.1_, the result is almost the same as in _v12.2_ i.e. when `Np=10` the calculation fails at about `t=7.1299`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the DQM is implemented correctly, then this may be an essential limitation of the method. I knew nothing about DQM, but scanning [this paper](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/appliedmechanicsreviews/article-abstract/49/1/1/401139), I have the feeling the method is similar to `Pseudospectral`. Indeed, a quick test shows that, the weighting coefficient matrix of 1st order derivative in DQM is exactly the same as the differentiation matrix of 1st order derivative in pseudospectral method:

```
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, X, DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"][
  "DifferentiationMatrix"] == C1[[All, All, 1]]
(* True *)
```

Though I can't give a concrete example at the moment, I did observe that `Pseudospectral` may become unstable when the spatial grid points increase in certain cases. Let's test if your problem belongs to such sort of thing. Because of the special b.c., we can't use `NDSolve` directly to solve the problem, so let's discretize the system in $x$ direction by ourselves. I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the task.

```
G1 = 0.05; Ω = 1; μ = 0.05; tmax = 10; a = 30; α = -0.001;
Lg = 1; bt = 1.8751/Lg; C0 = 1.8751^-4;

icrhs = 0.5 a ((Cos[bt x] - Cosh[bt x]) - 0.734 (Sin[bt x] - Sinh[bt x]));

With[{w = w[x, t]}, 
  eqn = D[w, t, t] + μ D[w, t] + C0 D[w, {x, 4}] == 0;
  bc = {(w /. x -> 0) == (2 G1 Cos[2 Ω t] (w + α w^3) /. x -> 1), 
        D[w, x] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
        {D[w, x, x] == 0, D[w, {x, 3}] == 0} /. x -> 1};
  ic = {w == icrhs, D[w, t] == 0} /. t -> 0];

Off[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative::ordred]

domain = {0, 1};
CGLGrid[{xl_, xr_}, n_] := 1/2 (xl + xr + (xl - xr) Cos[(π Range[0, n - 1])/(n - 1)]);

del = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;

help[points_] := (grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
  grid = N@CGLGrid[domain, points];
  difforder = points;
  (*Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
    please find it in the link above.*)
  ptoofunc = pdetoode[w[x, t], t, grid, difforder];
  ode = ptoofunc[eqn] // del;
  odeic = del /@ ptoofunc[ic];
  odebc = {ptoofunc@bc[[1, 1]] == ptoofunc@bc[[1, -1]], ptoofunc@bc[[2 ;;]]};
  NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, w@grid[[-1]], {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> ∞])

wRlst = Table[help[points], {points, 6, 10}];

ListLinePlot /@ wRlst
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[help[11], PlotRange -> {-30, 30}]
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 2.356194489774355`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

[image]

As we can see, when the number of grid points is no more than 10, the solution seems to be stable and converge quite fast, but once the `points` increases to `11`, the solution becomes wild, similar to the behavior of OP's implementation.

So, how to circumvent? Using low order difference formula to discretize turns out to be effective:

```
points = 50; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[w[x, t], t, grid, difforder];
ode = ptoofunc[eqn] // del;
odeic = del /@ ptoofunc[ic];
odebc = {ptoofunc@bc[[1, 1]] == ptoofunc@bc[[1, -1]], ptoofunc@bc[[2 ;;]]};
tst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, w@grid[[-1]], {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> ∞];

ListLinePlot[tst, PlotRange -> {-30, 30}]
```

[image]

As shown above, the solution remains stable with `points = 50; difforder = 2`.

`difforder = 4` can also be used if you like.

---

### Addendum: Re-implementation of OP's Method

After a closer look at OP's code together with the paper linked at the beginning of this answer, I think I've understood what OP has implemented. The following is my implementation for the same method, which may be a bit more readable:

```
G1 = 0.05; Ω = 1; μ = 0.05; a = 30; C0 = 1/1.8751^4; Lg = 1; bt = 1.8751/Lg; α = -0.001;
tmax = 10;
domain = {0, 1};
CGLGrid[{xl_, xr_}, n_] := 1/2 (xl + xr + (xl - xr) Cos[(π Range[0, n - 1])/(n - 1)]);
points = 9;
grid = N@CGLGrid[domain, points];

d1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, grid, DifferenceOrder -> "Pseudospectral"][
   "DifferentiationMatrix"];
(* Alternative method for defining d1: *)
(*
Π[i_] := Times@@Delete[grid[[i]] - grid, {i}];
d1 = Table[If[i == k,0.,Π@i/((grid[[i]] - grid[[k]]) Π@k)], {i, points}, {k, points}];
Table[d1[[i, i]] = -Total@d1[[i]], {i, points}];
 *)
d1withbc = Module[{d = d1}, d[[1, All]] = 0.; d];
d2 = d1 . d1withbc;
d2withbc = Module[{d = d2}, d[[-1, All]] = 0.; d];
d3 = d1 . d2withbc;
d3withbc = Module[{d = d3}, d[[-1, All]] = 0.; d];
d4 = d1 . d3withbc;

W[t_] = Rest@Array[w[#][t] &, points];
w0 = 2 G1 Cos[2 Ω t] (w[points][t] + α w[points][t]^3);

eqns = W''[t] + μ W'[t] + C0 Rest[d4] . Flatten@{w0, W[t]} == 0 // Thread;

ξ = Rest@grid;
X0 = 0.5 a ((Cos[bt ξ] - Cosh[bt ξ]) - 0.734 (Sin[bt ξ] - Sinh[bt ξ]));
X0d = 0 ξ;
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, W[0] == X0, W'[0] == X0d}, W[t], {t, 0, tmax}, 
     MaxSteps -> ∞][[1]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Plot[w[points][t] /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Some further explanation: in this method the $\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}$ has been discretized in a recursive manner i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is discretized first (`C1[[All, All, 1]]` in OP's code, `d1` in my code) and the discretized $\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}$  is calculated using `Dot`. Still feel suspicious? OK, let's validate:

```
f[x_] = (x - 1/2)^6 + Sin[x];

ListPlot[{grid, #}\[Transpose] & /@ {f'[grid], d1.f[grid]}, PlotMarkers -> {"o", "x"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"exact f'", "approximated f'"}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{grid, #}\[Transpose] & /@ {f''[grid], d1.d1.f[grid]}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"o", "x"}, PlotLegends -> {"exact f''", "approximated f''"}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{grid, #}\[Transpose] & /@ {f'''[grid], d1.d1.d1.f[grid]}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"o", "x"}, PlotLegends -> {"exact f'''", "approximated f'''"}]
```

[image]

Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ and
$\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3}$ have all appeared as intermediate in the method, the b.c.s of OP's problem can be imposed by modifying the matrix directly, for example:

```
ListLinePlot[{grid, d1withbc . f[grid]}\[Transpose]]
```

[image]

As illustrated above, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big|_{x=0}=0$ has been imposed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (+1). It is very supportive to understand the reason of instability of DQM. Also your solution has clear implementation of `bc`.

Comment: This oscillations hold even for homogeneous `bc` like $w(0,t)=0$. Is it numerical effect?

Comment: @Alex Oops, I've made a mistake when defining `icrhs`, the `With[{x = 0.5 (1 - Cos[π x])},…` should be removed. Now there's no high frequency component. Thx for testing.

Comment: Thank you! Now it looks better.

Comment: Thank you @xzczd First It was very difficult for me to understand. And thanks for editing my question and making it more clear.

Comment: @xzczd can we direct solve 4th order PDE problems in Mathematica 12.2?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM It depends on what the problem is. As mentioned above, OP's problem cannot be solved directly with `NDSolve` because its b.c. is unusual.

Comment: @xzczd  which method for 4th order PDE problems has been used in Mathemtica12.2.0, Finite Difference?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM `MethodOfLines` for time integration and `TensorProductGrid` for spatial discretization, of course. The request [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199369/1871) hasn't yet been fulfilled.

Answer (score 7):

Since this code is implementation DQM for cantilever beam then we need to put right boundary condition to make this code stable with number of grid points `Np` changing. This is small modification only but it is works for any `Np`, for example

```
Np = 20; G1 = 0.05; Ω = 1; μ = 0.05; tmax = 10; a = 30;
ii = Range[1, Np]; X = 0.5 (1 - Cos[(ii - 1)/(Np - 1) π]); 
Xi[xi_] := Cases[X, Except[xi]];
M[xi_] := Product[xi - Xi[xi][[l]], {l, 1, Np - 1}]; C1 = 
 C3 = ConstantArray[0, {Np, Np, 4}];
Table[If[i != j, 
    C1[[i, j, 1]] = M[X[[i]]]/((X[[i]] - X[[j]]) M[X[[j]]])];, {i, 1, 
   Np}, {j, 1, Np}];
Table[C1[[i, i, 
     1]] = -Total[Cases[C1[[i, All, 1]], Except[C1[[i, i, 1]]]]];, {i, 1, Np}];
C3[[All, All, 1]] = C1[[All, All, 1]]; 
C3[[1, All, 1]] = 0 C1[[1, All, 1]];
C3[[All, All, 2]] = C1[[All, All, 1]].C3[[All, All, 1]];
C3[[Np, All, 2]] = 0 C1[[Np, All, 2]];
C3[[All, All, 3]] = C1[[All, All, 1]].C3[[All, All, 2]];
C3[[Np, All, 3]] = 0 C1[[Np, All, 2]];
C1[[All, All, 2]] = C1[[All, All, 1]].C1[[All, All, 1]];
C3[[All, All, 4]] = C1[[All, All, 1]].C3[[All, All, 3]];
C3r4 = N[C3[[All, All, 4]]]; C11 = C3r4[[1, 1]]; C0 = 1.8751^-4;
K1M = C0 C3r4[[2 ;; Np, 1 ;; Np]]; K1V = C0 C3r4[[2 ;; Np, 1]];
Y1[t_] := Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, 2, Np}];
a2 = Flatten[ConstantArray[1, {Np - 1, 1}]]; α = -0.001; 
Xb[t] = 2 G1 Cos[2 Ω t] (Subscript[x, Np][
     t] + α Subscript[x, Np][t]^3) Table[KroneckerDelta[Np, i], {i, 2, Np}];
YV[t] = Flatten[{0, Y1[t]}];
eqns = Thread[D[Y1[t], t, t] + μ D[Y1[t], t] + K1M.YV[t] == Xb[t]];
Lg = 1; bt = 1.8751/Lg; ξ = X[[2 ;; Np]];
y0 = -0.5 a (((Cos[bt*ξ] - Cosh[bt*ξ]) - 
     0.734*(Sin[bt*ξ] - Sinh[bt*ξ]))); X0 = -y0; X0d = 0 y0;

s = NDSolve[{eqns, Y1[0] == X0, Y1'[0] == X0d}, 
    Y1[t], {t, 0, tmax}]; // AbsoluteTiming
plot1 = Plot[Evaluate[Subscript[x, Np][t] /. First@s], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"Np = ", Np}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

With this approach we have to consider `Xb[t]` as external force applied to the arbitrary point `next` as

```
Xb[t] = 2 G1 Cos[
       2 Ω t] (Subscript[x, Np][
         t] + α Subscript[x, Np][t]^3) Table[
       KroneckerDelta[next, i], {i, 2, Np}];
```

In the case of `next=Np` we have code above. The main reason why original code produces unstable solution is the  matrix `K1M` definition taken from the paper Application of the Generalized Differential Quadrature Method to the Study of Pull-In Phenomena of MEMS Switches, by Hamed Sadeghian, Ghader Rezazadeh, and Peter M. Osterberg. We can redefine it as follows

```
Np = 10; G1 = .05; \[CapitalOmega] = 1; \[Mu] = 0.05; tmax = 10; a = \
30;
ii = Range[1, Np]; X = 0.5 (1 \[Minus] Cos[(ii - 1)/(Np - 1) \[Pi]]); 
Xi[xi_] := Cases[X, Except[xi]];
M[xi_] := Product[xi - Xi[xi][[l]], {l, 1, Np - 1}]; C1 = 
 ConstantArray[0, {Np, Np}];
Table[If[i != j, 
    C1[[i, j]] = M[X[[i]]]/((X[[i]] - X[[j]]) M[X[[j]]])];, {i, 
   Np}, {j, Np}];
Table[C1[[i, 
     i]] = -Total[Cases[C1[[i, All]], Except[C1[[i, i]]]]];, {i, Np}];
W1 = C1; W1[[1, All]] = 0.;

W2 = C1.W1; W2[[Np, All]] = 0.;
 W3 = C1.W2; W3[[Np, All]] = 0.;
W4 = C1.W3; W4[[1, All]] = 0.;

C0 = 1.8751^-4; K1M = C0 W4;
Y1[t_] := Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, 1, Np}]; Y4 = K1M.Y1[t];
\[Alpha] = -0.001; Xb = 
 2 G1 Cos[2 \[CapitalOmega] t] (Subscript[x, Np][
     t] + \[Alpha] Subscript[x, Np][t]^3) Table[
   KroneckerDelta[1, i], {i, 1, Np}];
eqns = Thread[D[Y1[t], t, t] + \[Mu] D[Y1[t], t] + Y4 == Xb];
Lg = 1; bt = 1.8751/Lg; \[Xi] = X;
y0 = -0.5 a (((Cos[bt*\[Xi]] - Cosh[bt*\[Xi]]) - 
     0.734*(Sin[bt*\[Xi]] - Sinh[bt*\[Xi]]))); X0 = -y0; X0d = 0 y0;

s = NDSolve[{eqns, Y1[0] == X0, Y1'[0] == X0d}, Y1[t], {t, 0, tmax}];
```

We can compare this solution at `Xb=0`(red points) with solution generated by  xzczd code with `points=10` (solid line)
[image: Figure 2]

Now if we put `Np=30` and apply `Xb` to the first point as in the code above, then we get picture for every grid point as follows

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[Subscript[x, i][t] /. First@s], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"i = ", i}]], {i, 1, Np}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

This is very common respond to the external force. Using this matrix `K1M = C0 W4` we can realize main idea of `Xb` implementation as $x_1(t)$ as follows

```
Np = 12; G1 = .05; \[CapitalOmega] = 1; \[Mu] = 0.05; tmax = 20; a = \
30;
ii = Range[1, Np]; X = 0.5 (1 \[Minus] Cos[(ii - 1)/(Np - 1) \[Pi]]); 
Xi[xi_] := Cases[X, Except[xi]];
M[xi_] := Product[xi - Xi[xi][[l]], {l, 1, Np - 1}]; C1 = 
 ConstantArray[0, {Np, Np}];
Table[If[i != j, 
    C1[[i, j]] = M[X[[i]]]/((X[[i]] - X[[j]]) M[X[[j]]])];, {i, 
   Np}, {j, Np}];
Table[C1[[i, 
     i]] = -Total[Cases[C1[[i, All]], Except[C1[[i, i]]]]];, {i, Np}];
W1 = C1; W1[[1, All]] = 0.;

W2 = C1 . W1; W2[[Np, All]] = 0.;
 W3 = C1 . W2; W3[[Np, All]] = 0.;
W4 = C1 . W3; W4[[1, All]] = 0.;
C0 = 1.8751^-4; K1M = C0 W4;
Y1[t_] := Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, 1, Np}]; Y4 = K1M . Y1[t];
\[Alpha] = -0.001; Xb = 
 2 G1 Cos[2 \[CapitalOmega] t] (Subscript[x, Np][
     t] + \[Alpha] Subscript[x, Np][t]^3); force = (D[Xb, t, 
     t] + \[Mu] D[Xb, t]) Table[KroneckerDelta[1, i], {i, 1, Np}];
eqns = Thread[D[Y1[t], t, t] + \[Mu] D[Y1[t], t] + Y4 == force]; eq1 =
  eqns[[1]] /. 
  Solve[Last[eqns], (Subscript[x, 10]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]]; eqns1 = 
 Join[{eq1}, Rest[eqns]];
Lg = 1; bt = 1.8751/Lg; \[Xi] = X;
y0 = -0.5 a (((Cos[bt*\[Xi]] - Cosh[bt*\[Xi]]) - 
     0.734*(Sin[bt*\[Xi]] - Sinh[bt*\[Xi]]))); X0 = -y0; X0d = 0 y0;
s = NDSolve[{eqns1, Y1[0] == X0, Y1'[0] == X0d}, Y1[t], {t, 0, tmax}];
Table[Plot[Evaluate[Subscript[x, i][t] /. First@s], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"i = ", i}]], {i, 1, Np}]
```

[image: Figure 4]
Finally we can check that `Xb` and $x_1(t)$ are differ by a constant about 0.3. We can include this constant in the initial condition for $x_1(t)$ but it could be better to stay with $x_1(0)=0$ as in the code above. Also we should note, that proposed algorithm not stable for arbitrary `Np`,  but we can make it stable by increasing $\mu$ for the boundary point $x_1$ as it usually we did in the method of lines.

```
{Plot[{Evaluate[Xb /. First@s /. t -> t], 
   Evaluate[Subscript[x, 1][t] /. First@s]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[{Evaluate[Xb /. First@s /. t -> t] - 
    Evaluate[Subscript[x, 1][t] /. First@s]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: The usage of numerical viscosity restricts very high values, but the result remains incorrect while increasing tmax value. I have checked through comparison that the numerical method (differential quadrature) has been applied correctly. I think the solver is not able to carry out simulation for excitation " Xb[t]=2 G1 Cos[2 Ω t ] Subscript[x,Np][t]."   Thank you

Comment: @Hari This is a positive feedback what you try to simulate. Usually in this case system works as amplifier dependent on viscosity. For example, there are laminar and turbulent flow and transition between. Therefore system turns to chaos and standard numerical methods not applicable in this case.

Comment: As harmonic term is multiplied with the dependent variable, it becomes parametric type excitation. In this case, instability-chaos happens with large amplitude, but with mainly certain frequencies in the response... And also, Np is just number of grid points. So, solution should not vary drastically.

Comment: @Hari If numerical method depends on number of points like in this example then it means that we need to develop a new one.

Comment: Certainly, it shouldn't depend. But It works perfectly for all other different types of excitation for all values of Np. So, there should be some failure in simulation while solving for feedback based parametric type excitation....

Comment: @Hari What is the physical reason for this kind of parametric excitation?

Comment: Response of the free end of cantilever beam is multiplied by cos(2 \Omega t) and sent for excitation. Here, \Omega is close to a natural frequency... @Alex If some specific solver setting cannot be used, then what is general approach for such cases? Thank you very much

Comment: @Hari Did you read my answer to this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187448/dynamic-nonlinear-damped-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation ?

Answer (score 2):

```
thisstep = 0;
laststep = 0;
stepsize = 0;

First@NDSolve[{eqns, Y1[0] == X0, Y1'[0] == X0d}, Y1[t], {t, 0, tmax},
   MaxStepFraction -> 1/15, 
  StepMonitor :> (laststep = thisstep; thisstep = t;
    stepsize = thisstep - laststep;), 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}, 
    Method -> {"EventLocator", 
      "Event" :> (If[stepsize < 10^-9, 0, 1])}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 24.05]

ReImPlot[#, {t, 0, laststep}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, laststep}, {900, -900}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
   PlotLabels -> {"Expressions", "ReIm"}] & /@ %183[[All, 2]]
```

[image]

```
laststep
```

(* 7.12986 *)

```
ReImPlot[#, {t, 0, 7}, PlotRange -> Full, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"] & /@ %183[[2 ;; 9, 2]]
```

[image]

```
ReImPlot[%183[[1, 2]], {t, 0, laststep}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
 PlotLabels -> {"Expressions", "ReIm"}]
```

[image]

```
StepDataPlot[%183]
```

[image]

The first channel oscillates fastest and the amplitude is enlarging exponentially. Each method option for goals or precision is able to compute the oscillations with enormous power so that all other channels grow only exponentially. In a range form computing this constant there are oscillations.

The optimization is done with the perspective of the longest domain for the solution. Since all solution channels are dominated by $x_{1}$ that is most important.

Cutting the domain allows for an informative view:

```
ReImPlot[%183[[1, 2]], {t, 0, 4.3}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
 PlotLabels -> {"Expressions", "ReIm"}]
```

[image]

The solution of $x_{1}$ consist of a slower oscillation with a time-dependent frequency that the frequency gets faster with time. It oscillates below this slower envelop with a slowly with time deaccelerating but much faster frequency.

The plot is imprecise because of inferences up to noise in the plot. The `ColorFunction` shows that the oscillation go through zero. The envelope is asymmetric in the amplitudes with respect to the x-axis.

It is a chance that the singularity at 7.12986 and a little later can be computed stable with an enhanced methodology.

The best approaches are

```
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, Y1[0] == X0, Y1'[0] == X0d}, Y1[t], {t, 0, tmax},
    Method -> {"Extrapolation", Method -> "ExplicitModifiedMidpoint", 
     "StiffnessTest" -> False}, WorkingPrecision -> 32];

ReImPlot[%198[[1, 1, 2]], {t, 0, 4.3}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
```

[image]

```
ReImPlot[#, {t, 0, 7}, PlotRange -> Full, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"] & /@ %198[[1, 2 ;; 9, 2]]
```

[image]

Between both methods, there is only a little difference both are high-precision. But the solutions are different. Both compute noise and error at most from the fast oscillations. But the smaller the solutions step in time the more error and noise do add up.

The extrapolation diverges much faster at the critical time `7.12986` but in subintervals, the solutions in the other channels are less heavily oscillating. A subdivision of the domain may lead to less oscillation due to the less accumulated bending supposed the boundaries are taken with care. There is a chance to integrate less noise and error by smoothing the oscillation by adopting extrapolation.

My problem is that ["Extrapolation" Method for NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExtrapolation.html#777991017) is incomplete in examples. Mathematica on the other side does very much internally. That may too because of the high degree of similarity between both presented methods groups. The computation is very fast. There is an optimum `WorkingPrecision`. That can not be enhanced further. The length of the domain has an optimum value. That makes me skeptical.

I have got the concept that is just a pulse of finite height and that the curve calms in a process of power annihilation down. There no catastrophic event ahead. But the divergence is very fast many order in very small steps. The computing always ends are the message similar to the stiffness message the step size gets too small. That can not be overcome with the avoidance of inappropriate stiffness switching.

Proper integration of all the small-time oscillations may need much more time and computing power than I can offer for this answer.

The advantage in the first part of the computed domain is well visualized by:

[image]

The extrapolated solutions are much less oscillating in the more linear subinterval. It gains the same oscillations at the very start and in the subinterval greater than $⁄pi$. The oscillation momentum is much higher at the upper boundary of the domain than with the Stiffnessswitching. This is a comparison of the solution that is selected in the question.

Evaluating the `StepDataPlot` shows that in these subintervals the stiffnessswitching takes place. Inbetween no stiffnessswiching is executed. This makes these computations much faster than the ones from the question.

The strategic question is whether the oscillations at amplitude $-30$ are considered error/noise or are part of the solution. Since the Runge-Kutta method is designed for zeroing the error and noise the question is rather important. The result is transformable into the idea that computing on subintervals is an optimization to computing over the complete interval.

NDSolve does such canceling internally to some extent already. In the literature, this phenomenon may be called a rainbow or path into chaos with divergence. As can be taken from the programed event control of the stepsize this approach does not work. It is adapted from a question where NDSolve is operating on a solution with many branches. It did not detect branches at all.

The subdivision is probably the best especially if the amplitude is absolutely bigger than $15$. The values for the numerical experiments are taken from the question. Most probable there is more of interest.

For conducting some research what this is really doing look at [understanding of method for NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46406/understanding-of-method-for-ndsolve):

Select[Flatten[
Trace[NDSolve[system],
TraceInternal -> True]], ! FreeQ[#, Method | NDSolve`MethodData] &]

Ask Yourself: [What are the Wolfram Mathematica NDSolve function methods?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83156/what-are-the-wolfram-mathematica-ndsolve-function-methods)

"Adams" - predictor - corrector Adams method with orders 1 through 12
"BDF" - Gear implicit backward differentiation formulas with orders 1 
through 5
"ExplicitRungeKutta" -
adaptive embedded pairs of 2 (1) through 9 (8) Runge - Kutta methods
"ImplicitRungeKutta" - families of arbitrary - order implicit Runge -
Kutta methods
"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta" - interleaved Runge -
Kutta methods for separable Hamiltonian systems
"MethodOfLines" - method of lines for solution of PDEs
"Extrapolation" - (Gragg -) Bulirsch -
Stoer extrapolation method, with possible submethods
[Bullet] "ExplicitEuler" - forward Euler method
[Bullet] "ExplicitMidpoint" - midpoint rule method
[Bullet] "ExplicitModifiedMidpoint" -
midpoint rule method with Gragg smoothing
[Bullet] "LinearlyImplicitEuler" - linearly implicit Euler method
[Bullet] "LinearlyImplicitMidpoint" -
linearly implicit midpoint rule method
[Bullet] "LinearlyImplicitModifiedMidpoint" -
linearly implicit Bader - smoothed midpoint rule method
"DoubleStep" - "baby" version of "Extrapolation"
"LocallyExact" -
numerical approximation to locally exact symbolic solution
"StiffnessSwitching" -
allows switching between nonstiff and stiff methods in the middle of 
the integration
"Projection" - invariant - preserving method
"OrthogonalProjection" -
method that preserves orthonormality of solutions
"IDA" - general purpose solver for the initial value problem for 
systems of differential - algebraic equations (DAEs)
"Shooting" - shooting method for BVPs
"Chasing" - Gelfand - Lokutsiyevskii chasing method for BVPs
"EventLocator" -
event location for detecting discontinuities, periods, etc
"FiniteElements" - finite elements problems

Use [Monitoring And Selecting Algorithms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MonitoringAndSelectingAlgorithms.html):

```
try[m_] := 
 Block[{s = e = 0}, 
  NDSolve[system, StepMonitor :> s++, EvaluationMonitor :> e++, 
   Method -> m]; {s, e}]
```

with the Method and options of real interest and good solutions. It is sad that this tutorial does go really in depths. The selection process consumes much time.

This demonstrations shows the methodology of favor: [Adaptive 3D Plotting](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Adaptive3DPlotting/) at the task of plotting a 3D surface. This is a demonstration from Stephen Wolfram himself. And there are more of this. There is one for x-y-plotting: [Adaptive Plotting](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AdaptivePlotting/). This tutorials shows ["DoubleStep" Method for NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDoubleStep.html). It offers a look into why Runge-Kutta-method is successful for this problem. This tutorial somewhat and somehow drives the reader to the complex hidden behind the `Method` option `"Automatic"` that is so omnipresent in NDSolve solution in the literature, Mathematica documentation. Good practice is  [how to obtain adaptive sampling as in plot function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82912/how-to-obtain-adaptive-sampling-as-in-plot-function).

The problem is similar to that denoted by "for NIntegrate you should force numeric evaluation, otherwise it might employ some quadrature scheme that minimizes the number of eval points."

and

"From the symbolic form of the integrand NIntegrate can detect some its features like periodicity in order to minimize the number of evaluation points. AFAIK it will apply symbolic until you switch it off with Method->{Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing"->None} (instead of Automatic may be explicit method specification) or by using the "black box" method (_?NumericQ). Both ways do not disable the quadrature scheme."

A nice concept for a subdivision is given in [speed up contour plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-contourplot-on-multi-core-machines/1011#1011)[adaptive sampling for slow to compute functions in 2d](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216/adaptive-sampling-for-slow-to-compute-functions-in-2d) from this community.

The given problem with the given data is non stiff but gets stiff if the precision option from the question are taken that stiff. As can be confirmd by studying the Mathematica documentation the choice of recommendation is solely `WorkingPrecision`.

Work with [how to splice together several instances of interpolatingfunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction)! The important step ahead is the each full period has to be taken properly into account. Nice method for subdivision is documented in [NDSolve EventLocator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html)

Comment: Do you believe that instabilities are due to the method of ODE's system solution and not forced by definition of DQM matrix?

Comment: Believes are not really my field of research. I am the perspective, that proper subdivision of the large interval will gain some less error and noise. This is a large scale transformation. Optimized the interval length for example for the RK-method 3rd order and keep error and noise small instead of the presented large domain computation.