# Different results from NDSolve of v9 and v11

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

When using `NDSolve` to solve 2 pdes with different version of Mathematica, I obtained totally different results. The code is as follows.

```
L = 2*π; c = 1/20; ϵ = 35/100; α = 54/10; β = 35/100; (*parameters*)
(*define functions*)
cF0[z_, t_] := (8 - q[z, t]*S[z, t]*Log[S[z, t]/β])/(15*Log[S[z, t]/β] - 8*Log[S[z, t]/α]);
cA0[z_, t_] := (15 - q[z, t]*S[z, t]*Log[S[z, t]/α])/(15*Log[S[z, t]/β] - 8*Log[S[z, t]/α]);
F[z_, t_] := (cA0[z, t]*D[S[z, t], z])/S[z, t] + D[cA0[z, t], z]*Log[S[z, t]/β];
p0[z_, t_] := -(1/S[z, t]) + ϵ^2*D[S[z, t], {z, 2}] + 30/(2*S[z, t]^2)*(15*cF0[z, t]^2 - 8*cA0[z, t]^2);

(*pdes*)
eqS = 8*D[S[z, t]^2, t] == D[(1 - ϵ*D[p0[z, t], z])*(α^2 - S[z, t]^2)^2 - 
 2*S[z, t]*((1 - ϵ*D[p0[z, t], z])*S[z, t] + 60*ϵ*q[z, t]*F[z, t])*(α^2 - S[z, t]^2 + 
    2*S[z, t]^2*Log[S[z, t]/α]), z];

eqQ = D[q[z, t], t] + (1/4*(1 - ϵ*D[p0[z, t], z])*(α^2 - S[z, t]^2 + 
      2*S[z, t]^2*Log[S[z, t]/α]) + ϵ*30*q[z, t]*S[z, t]*F[z, t]*Log[S[z, t]/α])*D[q[z, t], z] + 
q[z, t]*(1/8*(1 - α^2/S[z, t]^2 + 2*Log[S[z, t]/α])*D[(1 - ϵ*D[p0[z, t], z])*S[z, t]^2 + 60*ϵ*q[z, t]*S[z, t]*F[z, t], z] - 
   1/16*ϵ*D[p0[z, t], {z, 2}]*(2*α^2 - 3*S[z, t]^2 + α^4/S[z, t]^2) + ϵ*30*q[z, t]*F[z, t]*D[S[z, t], z]) == 1/S[z, t]*(16*cF0[z, t] - 7*cA0[z, t]);

(*initial conditions*)
SeedRandom[1]
iniS[z_] = 22/5 + c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 50], SplineClosed -> True][z/L];
SeedRandom[2]
iniq[z_] = 1/8 + c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 50], SplineClosed -> True][z/L];

endtime = 400 (*600*);  nZ = 1001; xdifforder = 6;
eqns = {eqS, eqQ, S[z, 0] == iniS[z], q[z, 0] == iniq[z],
S[0, t] == S[L, t],
Derivative[1, 0][S][0, t] == Derivative[1, 0][S][L, t],
Derivative[2, 0][S][0, t] == Derivative[2, 0][S][L, t],
Derivative[3, 0][S][0, t] == Derivative[3, 0][S][L, t],
q[0, t] == q[L, t], Derivative[1, 0][q][0, t] == Derivative[1, 0][q][L, t]};

{solnS, solnQ} = NDSolveValue[eqns, {S, q}, {z, 0, L}, {t, 0, endtime}, MaxSteps -> ∞, Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
"Method" -> "LSODA", "TemporalVariable" -> t, "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
  "MinPoints" -> nZ, "MaxPoints" -> nZ, "DifferenceOrder" -> xdifforder}}]
```

When I run above code in v9.0 and v11.3, it gives different result when plotting with

```
Splot = Plot[solnS[z, 400], {z, 0, L}, PlotRange -> {{0, L},All}, Axes -> False, 
Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.3, ImageSize -> 600, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

My findings:

1. v9 gives a plausible result and runs faster than v11.3 in general;
2. v9 yields a larger data than v11.3 with the same code;
3. Since I am suspicious of the results, I found the `fix` function by @xzczd [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129183/ndsolve-uses-different-difference-order-for-different-spatial-derivative-when-so/133253#133253), which allows us to have more control into the black box. So, I tried it as well (**note `fix` function can only be used in v9**), but the result is also very different from that of v9 with non-fixed difference order (6th-order) when running up to a longer time, for example, `endtime=600`.

   ```
    {solnS, solnQ} = fix[endtime, xdifforder]@NDSolveValue[eqns, {S, q}, {z, 0, L}, {t, 0, endtime},
    MaxSteps -> ∞, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "Method" -> "LSODA", 
    "TemporalVariable" -> t, "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> nZ, "MaxPoints" -> nZ, "DifferenceOrder" -> xdifforder}}]
   ```
4. As required in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128447/conservation-of-area-solving-a-pde-via-finite-difference-scheme), I check the conservation of volume with

   ```
    volume = ListPlot[Table[Quiet@NIntegrate[π*solnS[z, t]^2, {z, 0, L}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}], {t, 0, tmax, 1}], PlotRange -> All]
   ```

With the `fix` function, I get more than 5% error between the initial volume `iniVol = N[π*(α - 1)^2*L]` and the finial one. **This may be an example to explain why `NDSolve` chooses different difference orders for spatial derivatives.**

In principle, I could reduce the error by in increasing mesh. However, even increasing to `nZ = 2001` (**note: do not run with `nZ = 2001` because it ran > 20hrs on my desktop and the data become too larger to save**), both v9 and v11 give a warning : >> estimated initial error on the specified spatial grid in the direction of independent variable z exceeds prescribed error tolerance. Btw, with `nZ = 1801` the code will run for 12+ hrs and the data have a reasonable size to be saved.

5. I also tried `"DifferenceOrder"->"Pseudospectral"`, which gave an obviously wrong result (noise and zig-zag)

Dose anyone have any suggestions? My objective is to have the volume conserved to within about 0.01%. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Versions you testing are  too old. We now testing v.12.3, and they promise us v.13 soon.

Comment: @AlexTrounev if my problem can be solved in these new versions, I am happy with it.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Version 9 isn't bad for the problem. See my answer below.

Comment: This may be a complete shot in the dark, but have you tested whether ``SeedRandom[1]; RandomReal[{-1, 1}]`` gives the same result in both versions?

Comment: @Domen Thanks! I just tested, `SeedRandom[1]; RandomReal[{-1, 1}]` gives completely the same result in v9.0 and v11.3 at least.

Comment: @Nobody This problem can be solved in v.12.3 with code by xzczd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the experience obtained in [these posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230431/1871), we know if conservation law involves in a PDE/PDE system, it's better not to *expand* the equation, and this is true not only for the spatial derivative, but also for the temporal derivative.

If I read it right, `S[z, t]` is always larger than `0`, so let's introduce a new variable `S2[z, t]` that satisfies `S2[z, t] == S[z, t]^2` to avoid the expansion of `D[S[z, t]^2, t]`:

```
$Version
(* "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 13, 2013)" *)

(* Code that's not modified is omitted here *)
srule = S -> (Sqrt[S2[#, #2]] &);

eqS = 8*D[S2[z, t], t] == 
   D[(1 - ϵ*D[p0[z, t], z])*(α^2 - S[z, t]^2)^2 - 
     2*S[z, t]*((1 - ϵ*D[p0[z, t], z])*S[z, t] + 
     60*ϵ*q[z, t]*F[z, t])*(α^2 - S[z, t]^2 + 2*S[z, t]^2*Log[S[z, t]/α]), z];

eqns = {eqS, eqQ,
        S2[z, 0] == iniS[z]^2, q[z, 0] == iniq[z],
        S2[0, t] == S2[L, t], q[0, t] == q[L, t]} /. srule;

mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

{solnS2, solnQ} = 
   NDSolveValue[eqns, {S2, q}, {z, 0, L}, {t, 0, endtime}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
    Method -> mol[100, 4]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {14.470040, Null} *)

S2plot = Plot[solnS2[z, 400], {z, 0, L}, PlotRange -> {{0, L}, All}, Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.3, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

> **Remark**
>
> I've simplified the code for the periodic b.c.s a bit, but it's
> equivalent to the original. Actually according to the observation in
> [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182050/1871), even
> a single `q[0, t] == q[L, t]` is enough to specify periodic b.c.s for
> all the variables.

Increasing spatial grid points to `200` visually doesn't change the solution. I've also tested in *v12.3*, the solution looks the same. Finally, the solution obeys the conservation law well:

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Quiet@NIntegrate[solnS2[z, t], {z, 0, L}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], {t, 0, endtime, 10}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

So I think it's safe to say the solution is reliable.

Comment: thank you, but your bcs appear to be different from mine.

Comment: @Nobody It's the same, actually even a single `q[0, t] == q[L, t]` is enough to specify periodic b.c. for all the variables. This is observed in the following post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182050/1871

Comment: It looks like in v.12.3 we have similar results with your code, nice approach (+1).

Comment: @xzczd thank you, by increasing mesh to `n=600` the warning remains: estimated initial error on the specified spatial grid in the direction of independent variable z exceeds prescribed error tolerance. Is the result reliable? After experimentation, I found as mesh increases, the quality of the results may decrease!

Comment: `eerri` is merely a warning. (For example, it never disappears for a unsmooth initial condition. ) As mentioned in the answer, with different grid size the solution is virtually the same, so the solution is probably reliable. @nobody

Comment: @xzczd 1. "let's introduce `S2[z, t] == S[z, t]^2` ... ", as `S2[z, t] == S[z, t]^2` is not a command in the code, so it should be better to write as "introduce $S2[z, t] = S[z, t]^2$ ..."; 2. do you think your `fix` function does not make things better in my case and thus it may be an example to explain why `NDSolve` chooses different difference orders for spatial derivatives?

Comment: @Nobody 1. I'm sorry, but $S2[z,t]$ is just terrible in my eyes. I've clarified my answer a bit, hopefully it's better now. 2. Yes, this example shows the design of `"DifferenceOrder"` may lead to better result compared to a fixed order difference discretization in certain cases.

Comment: @xzczd I found with pseudospectral method, there is even no an `eerri` warning. Could you give a hint about the reason why pseudospectral method fails to give a reasonable result in this case? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nobody 1. Using the modified equation in my answer, the result given by `Pseudospectral` isn't too unreasonable. (The efficiency is much worse though. Try e.g. `mol[35]` ) 2. Of course there exist examples that `Pseudospectral` fail to handle, but sadly I don't know the reason, related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237545/1871